# display exotic characters with curses under Windows 8 and Python 3.3

Tags: python, windows-8, utf-8, ascii, curses

i'd like to do something like this :

```
for i in range(9780, 9801):
    print(chr(i))

☴
☵
☶
☷
☸
☹
☺
☻
☼
☽
☾
☿
♀
♁
♂
♃
♄
♅
♆
♇
♈
```

but i don't know how to do it working under windows 8 with curses and Python 3.
 Friends can do that but with Mac OS or Linux.

Somebody have any idea ? 
I need to display the smiley symbol instead of @ symbol.

Comment: related :  http://static.flickr.com/87/240803829_9212773615_o.png

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024/how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075102/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using-when-it-is-started

Comment: What happened when you tried the code in the question? Did it work?

Comment: Is your Python interpreter linked with PDCurses, ncurses, or what? In the case of PDCurses, you'd want to use the wide-character build.

Comment: Note that `print()` doesn't go through curses, in any case. For that, you need `printw()`.